# aggregate logs into oracle db with flume

Tags: flume

I want to aggregate log files (10GB everyday), extract the ERROR logs, and then write them into an Oracle DB, can I use apache-flume to achieve this?

I read the [document](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html) but did not find anything like "Oracle Sink", so I am going to create a custom Sink to write flume events to Oracle. Is it a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, creating a custom sink is the right way to go. It's fairly easy to do. Look at the source code for the built-in sinks, such as the Avro Sink, to get started.